# GAP semidirect product algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gap, computational-algebra, semidirect-product

Can anybody guide me towards, or possibly even explain here, the algorithm that GAP uses to compute the semidirectproduct of two permutation groups which outputs another permutation group?

EXAMPLE:

> gap> C3:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,3); 
>  Group([ (1,2,3) ]) 
>   gap> C7:=CyclicGroup(IsPermGroup,7); 
>  Group([ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ])
>   
>  gap> A:=AutomorphismGroup(C7); 
>  < group with 1 generators > 
>  gap> elts :=
>   Elements(A); 
>  [ IdentityMapping( Group([ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ]) ),
>   
>    [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] -> [ (1,3,5,7,2,4,6) ], 
>    [
>   (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] -> [ (1,4,7,3,6,2,5) ], 
>    [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ]
>   -> [ (1,5,2,6,3,7,4) ], 
>    [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] -> [ (1,6,4,2,7,5,3) ], 
>    [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] -> [ (1,7,6,5,4,3,2) ]
>   ] 
>  gap> sigma := elts[2]; 
>  [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
>   ] -> [ (1,3,5,7,2,4,6) ] 
>  gap> sigma^3; 
>  [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ]
>   -> [ (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] 
>  gap> map := GroupHomomorphismByImages(C3, A, GeneratorsOfGroup(C3), [sigma]); 
>  [ (1,2,3) ] -> [ [
>   (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ] -> [ (1,3,5,7,2,4,6) ] ] 
>  gap> SDP :=
>   SemidirectProduct(C3, map, C7); 
>  Group([ (2,3,5)(4,7,6),
>   (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) ])

Comment: The code is on line 919 of lib/gprdperm.gi I'll look over it to see if it is easy to explain.

Comment: Oh my, yes it is very simple. A little scary. It rewrites the normal subgroup in its regular action (so $K$ acting on $|K|$ points), and then of course the complement subgroup acts on the normal subgroup giving the semidirect product of $H/C_H(K)$ with $K$. If $C_H(K) \neq 1$, then do the subdirect product smooshy thing with $H$'s original rep.

Comment: In particular, please don't try this with $S_{20}$ as the normal subgroup. :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is on line 919 of `lib/gprdperm.gi` and is very easy to understand.

It rewrites the normal subgroup in its regular action (so $K$ acting on $|K|$ points), and then of course the complement subgroup acts on the normal subgroup giving the semidirect product of $H/C_H(K)$ with $K$. If $C_H(K) \neq 1$, then it does the subdirect product smooshy thing with $H$'s original rep: that is $H \ltimes K$ acts on $X \dot\cup K$ where $H$ acts on $X$ as usual, $K$ centralizes $X$, and $H,K$ have the previously described action on $K$.

In particular, this method is impractical with $S_{20} as the normal subgroup.

If $K$ acts on $Y$ and $|H|$ is small, then $H \ltimes K$ can act on $H \times Y$ as well, but this is not implemented.

There is a special method implemented on line 961 to catch a nice case: if $K$ acts on $Y$, and if the action of $H$ on $K$ lifts to a homomorphism from $H$ to $\operatorname{Sym}(Y)$, then one can view $H$ more compactly as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X \dot\cup Y)$. This method is not guaranteed to succeed even if applicable if $C_{\operatorname{Sym}(Y)}(K)$ is large, as the method to check if the homomorphism lifts is just to choose a random section and see if it a homomorphism.