# Find generators of a group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, math-software, gap

This is a question in the mathematical software called [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html):

What is the command for displaying all the generators of a given group?

I have been searching around but yet not found anything helpful, so I am hoping I will get a quick response here.

Comment: May I ask what is your group? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS., I think there is no group specified in general, since I encountered this problem many times. In the current case, I construct the group $\mathbb{Z}_{25}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_5$ by modulus of a free group. But I still need to find out the generators due to construction purpose. Of course I can still use some other clumsy ways to find them out, but just not so nice and handy.

Comment: Have you tried to find a clear presentation of above semidirect prodct?

Comment: @BabakS., the presentation comes from modulus of a free group, so the elements in the free group can not be identified as the elements in the quotient group. Or maybe I am not sure what you mean..

Comment: Sorry. I mean $\mathbb Z_n⋊\mathbb Z_m=<a,b\mid a^n=b^m=1,bab^{-1}=a^l>,~~l^m\equiv 1~(mod~n),~~(l,n)=1$. Moreover there is a logical problem in the product above for $m=5,n=25$ since I cannot find that semidirectproduct by GAP. it shows an inconsistency.

Comment: @BabakS., I was using $\langle a,b|a^{25}=b^5=1,a^b=a^6\rangle$, which is same as what you got, but then?

Comment: @BabakS., semidirect product only works with associated action: e.g, SemidirectProduct(GL(2,3),GF(3)^2);

Comment: See this. I hope, till someone finds the proper codes, this helps you. :) http://math.stackexchange.com/q/178544/8581

Comment: Are u on, Easy?

Comment: @BabakS., command has been found from the GAP forum.

Comment: I knew that. You can find it easily via GAP help. But I want to construct the group first.

Comment: @BabakS., I can construct the group. Even you can construct the group using the method you mentioned in the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the command:

GeneratorsOfGroup( G );

Answer (score 7):

I think you may have in mind `GeneratorsOfGroup`. Enter `?GeneratorsOfGroup` in GAP to see the documentation.

---

*Remark*: It may be useful to extend this post by some hints on using the GAP help system from the GAP command line. A single question mark returns all manual sections (for GAP **and** packages) with the title *starting* from the given word, for example:

```
gap> ?generators
Help: several entries match this topic - type ?2 to get match [2]

[1] loops (not loaded): Generators
[2] Modules (not loaded): Generators
[3] Semigroups (not loaded): Generators
[4] Tutorial: GeneratorsOfSomething
...
[14] Reference: GeneratorsOfGroup
```

So, looking at entries 4 and/or 14 one would be able to find `GeneratorsOfGroup`.

Double question mark returns all manual sections whose title *contains* the given word, for example:

```
gap> ??Soluble                                                        
Help: several entries match this topic - type ?2 to get match [2]

[1] Reference: IsPSolubleCharacterTable
[2] Reference: IsPSolubleCharacterTableOp
[3] Reference: ComputedIsPSolubleCharacterTables
[4] Reference: Conjugacy Classes in Solvable Groups
[5] Reference: Irreducible Solvable Matrix Groups
[6] Reference: SupersolvableResiduum
[7] Reference: IsSolvableGroup
[8] Reference: IsSupersolvableGroup
[9] Reference: IsPSolvable
```

This also demonstrates another feature that recently appeared in GAP: the output below contains both versions, *solvable* and *soluble*. What happens is that the search system uses the internal variable `TRANSATL` (for *"transatlantic"* :) to search for the following pairs of spelling patterns:

```
gap> TRANSATL;
[ [ "atalogue", "atalog" ], [ "olour", "olor" ], [ "entre", "enter" ], 
  [ "isation", "ization" ], [ "ise", "ize" ], [ "abeling", "abelling" ], 
  [ "olvable", "oluble" ], [ "yse", "yze" ] ]
```

---

P.S. By default, the GAP help system displays the text version of the documentation. Using the [`SetHelpViewer` command](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap2.html#X87C1BFB2826488B0) (see `?SetHelpViewer`) one could set it to open its HTML-version in the browser, enjoying hyperlinks for navigation and MathJax support. Then one could add the call to `SetHelpViewer` to the `gap.ini` or `gaprc` file (see [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap3.html#X7FD66F977A3B02DF)) to use this setting for any new GAP session by default.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/683398/) for some more details.

Comment: Tried, but failed,:(

Comment: @Easy, what does fail in your case - getting generators or viewing the documentation?

Comment: I've now added some hints how one could try to find answers to similar questions using the GAP help system - hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I did the group according to the presentation you noted above:

```
F:=FreeGroup("a","b");;
a:=F.1;;
b:=F.2;; 
G:=F/[a^25,b^5,b*a*b^(-1)*a^(-6)];;
Size(G);
                                      125
StructureDescription(G);
                                  "C25 : C5"
```

Comment: Haha, that's exactly what I did!

Comment: Really! Nice to hear that, Easy. ;-)

Comment: Nice display! I need to start using GAP again. After all, I have a dear friend to turn to if I need to learn anything!

Comment: @amWhy: Easy made me to search and to learn the final line, Amy. Thanks Easy for this question. It deserves more than +1 for me.